# Is there an R function for fitting survival curves with IPW and competing risks?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival

I'm trying to fit survival curves:

1. with inverse probability weighting (IPW)
2. taking into account competing risks.

In the *RISCA* package, the function *ipw.survival* allows to fit survival curves with IPW but not with competing risks.

Can anyone help with this?
Could this be feasible with *survival* or *rms* packages

Answer (score 0):

It is generally not possible to estimate the survival function when competing risks are present. It is, however, possible to estimate the cause-specific cumulative incidence function, which is very similar. Multiple methods to adjust these curves for confounding factors have also been proposed in the literature. The `adjustedCurves` package implements most of these methods in the `adjustedcif` function. Here is an example from the documentation:

```
library(adjustedCurves)
library(survival)
library(riskRegression)

set.seed(42)

# simulate some example data
sim_dat <- sim_confounded_crisk(n=1000, max_t=1.2)
sim_dat$group <- as.factor(sim_dat$group)

# treatment assignment model to estimate the
# propensity score (which can be converted to inverse probability weights)
glm_mod <- glm(group ~ x2 + x3 + x5 + x6, data=sim_dat, family="binomial")

# using inverse probability of treatment weighting
adjcif <- adjustedcif(data=sim_dat,
                      variable="group",
                      ev_time="time",
                      event="event",
                      cause=1,
                      method="iptw",
                      treatment_model=glm_mod,
                      conf_int=TRUE)
plot(adjcif, conf_int=TRUE)
```

[image: cif]

A rigorous description can be found in the excellent article by Ozenne et al. (https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/bimj.201800298). A review and simulation studies for adjusted survival curves without competing risks can be found in my recent article on the topic (https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/sim.9681).